# Kentico Module Parent/Child Relationship - Using GUID instead of ID for parent reference

Tags: kentico

I set up a custom module within Kentico and then followed [this](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Setting+parent-child+relationships+for+classes) to create parent/child relationships between the classes in the module.  That works great and I have everything working using:

```
ChildParentID = {% ToInt(UIContext.ParentObjectID) %}
```

However, I want to use the parent's GUID as the foreign key, not their ID.  I am able to configure the info and info provider classes for the child to specify the GUID of the parent as the foreign key but I can't figure out how to actually get the parent GUID when retrieving the child classes.  I was hoping Kentico would provide an easy macro like:

```
ChildParentGUID = {% ToInt(UIContext.ParentObjectGUID) %}
```

but that doesn't exist and I'm not sure how to get the GUID of the parent in the macro.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use the GUID vs. the ID?

Comment: We've had issues importing sites that use the ID as the foreign key, all of the references are wrong when the rows get inserted into the new database and have to be redone.  By using the GUID we wouldn't have an issue when importing the site into another instance of Kentico.

Comment: When you're importing the site I'm assuming you're using the import/export functionality in the Admin interface correct?  If you use the Import Toolkit, I believe you can keep a foreign key mapping, which I'd think the import process would do as well but if it doesn't know has a child then it might not.  Have you contacted Kentico Support about the import issue and mappings?

Comment: Thanks Brenden, yes the importing has been through the import functionality in the admin interface.  I haven't contacted Kentico support yet, I was hoping it was just something simple that I missed.  I'll contact them now.

Comment: Based on creating several modules in Kentico 8 I know the ID is automatically included and is automatically placed in the URL to retrieve.  There may be a way to gather the GUID buy the ID passed in but I'm unsure of what that macro would look like.  Bad part about that as well is it would require another query when loading the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suggest you to reconsider to use ID as a parent reference. It will simplify other things for you automatically such as automatic deletion of children, proper inclusion within import/export/staging, etc.

You probably just don't have TypeInfo of those two classes set up properly.

Most typical mistake is that you list parent ID both as parentIdColumn in constructor, and in ObjectDependencies which is then causing unwanted double translation.

Can you post here your TypeInfo configurations for both classes?

You can also check my article to try out a specific scenario how to set it up [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/module-development-parent-child-relationships)

If you insist on using GUID for parent relation and it works for you, you can use the following to get related parent GUID:

```
{% UIContext.EditedObjectParent.GUID %}
```